# R pivoting data frame cells containing vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, pivot

I've got the following data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(id = 1:2,
                name = c("Jon", "Mark"),
                children = I(list(c("Mary", "James"),
                                  c("Greta", "Sally")))
)
```

I'd like to convert it from:

[image]
To something like this:

[image]

Comment: `tidyr::unnest(d)`, except I don't see why the id values should change in the indicated manner...

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution as proposed by Z.Lin 
tidyr::unnest(d)